# Redirecting pv output to file

Tags: linux, file, unix, command-line-interface, progress

I'm using the pv utility to asses the speed of log entries being added in a log file, like this:

```
tail -f -n 0 mylog.log | pv -lr -t -i 5 > /dev/null
```

This outputs the addition speed and refreshes every 5 sec:

```
0:00:05 [  10/s]
```

Now, I would like to redirect the current value ("10") to a file and refresh it every 5s. Not append it, just overwrite the previous value in the file. 
Any idea on how to do the redirection to file? I'm pretty new in unix and haven't got it to work yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pv` is writing its diagnostics to stderr, so you can start with:

```
tail -f -n 0 mylog.log | pv -lr -t -i 5 > /dev/null 2> output-file
```

This will merely append, so output-file will end up with all of the data with lines terminated by carriage returns without linefeeds.  (I don't have access to pv at the moment, so this is all conjecture.)  To get the data you want, try some simple post processing along the lines of:

```
tail -f mylog.log | pv -lr -t -i 5 2>&1 > /dev/null | 
  tr /\\r \ \\n | tr -d [] | while read stamp value;
  do echo $value > output-file; done
```

The shell technique above allows you to direct stderr into the pipe for post-processing.  Using tail like you're doing is a little odd, and pv is overkill for this. If you have such a long delay (5 seconds is a *long* time), it's probably acceptable to just use `wc` on each iteration and do subtraction:

```
echo 0 > output-file
while sleep 5; do
    expr $(wc -l < mylog.log) - $(cat output-file) > output-file
done
```

Note that this prints the difference over 5 seconds rather than a rate per second.  `expr` does not handle non-integer arithmetic very well, so dividing by 5 is problematic.  You could use `bc` or `dc` to get more precision, but you're probably better off not even doing subtraction and just writing the total number of lines to the file every few seconds.

Comment: Note that the last example (running `wc` on your log file every 5 seconds) is very dangerous if your log file can ever get large. Your server will spend all it's time re-reading the log file and not doing much else.

Comment: unfortunately "pv -lr -t -i 5 > /dev/null 2> output-file" writes nothing to output-file

Answer (score 4):

As I can't add a comment, I want to follow up on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801357/redirecting-pv-output-to-file#comment55631725_20802452)

Use the `-f` flag on `pv` to force its output to a file.

> -f, --force
>   Force output. Normally, pv will not output any visual display if standard error is not a terminal. This option forces it to do so.

e.g. `tail -f -n 0 mylog.log | pv -lrf -t -i 5 > /dev/null 2> output-file`

Comment: Much more straightforward solution

Answer (score 1):

If the byte count of the file is OK instead of the line count, you can do this:

```
while true; do
  ls -s --block-size=1 mylog.log > output-file
  sleep 5
end
```

This is much more efficient than using PV.  The "pv" command is burning a lot of CPU by copying all the bytes in your log.

Comment: Or use `wc -l` to do just what OP wants!

Comment: `wc` is still inefficient if your file is large. Looking at the file size is an O(1) operation. Counting the lines in the file is an O(N) operation, where N is the number of bytes in the file.

Comment: True, but if you really need the amount of lines, I see no other way.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers tell how to get pv to save to a file, but some are incomplete.  `pv` terminates each logged line with a `\r` (carriage return or CR) and not a `\n` (newline).  If you, for example, `cat pv-output-file`, it won't print each line separately to the screen, rather it'll print each line and then overwrite it almost instantly. `more` seems to behave somewhat better, but still not great, and `less` will give you the whole `pv` log on a single line rendered with a bunch of `^M`'s at what should be the end of each line.

To get it to render well in a text viewer, you'll still need to do something to translate the CR's to newlines.  There are any number of ways to do this in unix including `tr`, `sed`, `awk`, and even one of the `dos2unix` variants (I think it's `mac2unix` or `dos2unix -c mac`).

If you have perl installed, the following one-liner will print each line of pv-output-file on a separate line.

```sh
perl -pe 's/\r/\n/g' pv-output-file
```

You can redirect the output of that into a text viewer like `less` or `more` to scroll through the lines.  If you'd just want to 'fix' it in place, do `perl -pi -e [...]` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i got pv to pipe to file after looking through the other examples in this thread.

```
find / -name "*.txt" -exec cat -n {} \; 2>&1 \
| pv -fi1 --format $'pv1 %t %b %r \n' -s 1G --stop-at-size 2>pv1.txt \
| grep opt \
| pv -fi1 --format $'pv2 %t %b %r \n' 2>pv2.txt \
| wc
```

**Explanation:**

- **find** just generates text and 2>1 also send error down the pipe
- **pv1**  the -f force output for pv

  - -i1 every second pv output
  - --format '%t %b %r \n' to get time, bytes and speed with newline.
  - -s expected size 1Gig
  - --stop-at-size stop pipe if we reach 1Gig of text files
- **gzip** compresses data so less hit second pv
- **pv2** same as pv1 without the size
- **wc** count words so we have some output at the end.

Then view pv output with

```
cat pv1.txt ; sleep 2 ; cat pv2.txt
```

e.g.

```
pv1 0:00:01  811KiB [ 791KiB/s] 
pv1 0:00:02 1.23MiB [ 434KiB/s] 
pv1 0:00:03 1.24MiB [12.7KiB/s] 


pv2 0:00:01 0.00 B [0.00 B/s] 
pv2 0:00:02 0.00 B [0.00 B/s] 
pv2 0:00:03 4.00KiB [4.20KiB/s]
```